# Liferay login portlet display text change

Tags: liferay

Change display name in login portlet from “Screen Name” to “Username”. As per discussion in liferay forums I am assuming that it can be done by using creating hook. Is there any easy way to change the display text.

Comment: Be sure to include the version under which you are developing. I've only ever worked under 6.2 so I'm not well versed in the capabilities of older versions, but doing so will help others help you.

Comment: go for hook that overrides jsp for changing label.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As reported by discussion forum the best way to do it it's a hook. Your choice if you prefer change login jsp or change the "screen-name" resource bundle properties files. Be aware that changing screen-name label affect whole portal and wherever screen-name label was used (not only login portlet).

If you don't want write a hook, you can try to add to Liferay web application a file named Language-ext.properties within the WEB-INF\classes\content (if content dir doesn't exist create it). Edit Language-ext.properties and add a line with screen-name=Username. Restart Liferay. It should works.

Be aware that language specific version of Language properites files takes precedence over "-ext" version and location specific version takes precedence over language version. If your portal-impl contains language/location specific version you have to ovverride it with relative language specific ext file (e.g. Language-ext_en.properties)

Comment: I have created Language-ext.properties and added "screen-name=Username" but after restarting Liferay it is not working. Please suggest.

Comment: Be aware that language specific version of Language properites files takes precedence over "-ext" version and location specific version takes precedence over language version. If your portal-impl contains language/location specific version you have to ovverride it with relative language specific ext file (e.g. Language-ext_en.properties)